# Changing colors in an array

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make the colour of the asteroids cycle through red, green, blue when either the asteroids goes off screen or hit the ground. Here's the code I currently have:

```
float[] circleX;
float[] circleY;
float[] circledia;
float[] speedY;
float[] speedX;
int asteroid = 10;

void setup()
{
    size(600, 700);
    background(188, 234, 255);

    circleX = new float[asteroid];
    circleY = new float[asteroid];
    circledia = new float[asteroid];
    speedX = new float[asteroid];
    speedY = new float[asteroid];

    for (int i = 0; i < asteroid; i++)
    {
        circleX[i] = random(50, 500);
        circleY[i] = 0;
        circledia[i] = random(10, 50);
        speedX[i] = random(-2, 2);
        speedY[i] = random(2, 3);
    }
}

void draw()
{
    background(188, 234, 255);
    noStroke();
    fill(113, 69, 75);
    rect(0, 580, width, height);
    asteroidArr();
}
```

I think it has something to do with my void asteroidArr function, but I cannot figure out where to put a if statement for cycling each colour.

```
void asteroidArr()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < asteroid; i++)
    {
        noStroke();
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(circleX[i], circleY[i], circledia[i], circledia[i]);
        circleY[i] = circleY[i] + speedY[i];
        circleX[i] = circleX[i] + speedX[i];

        if (circleY[i] > 560 || circleX[i] < -10 || circleX[i] > 610)
        {
            circleY[i] = 0;
            circleX[i] = random(50, 500);
            circledia[i] = random(10, 50);
            speedY[i] = random(2, 2);
            speedX[i] = random(-2, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Standard c++ has no GUI or colors. You should add additional tags to explain what GUI you are using.

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking for. Try to rewrite the question and focus on the problem. In particular abstain from using non-problem-related terms like "asteroid", "go off screen", "hit the ground". Mention the libraries you are using, hard to tell what is `noStroke`, `fill`, `ellipse`, etc.

Comment: It's a standard Processing app which is a java-based language.  I don't understand the problem either; what good does it do to change the asteroid's color after it is offscreen or after it disappears when it hits the ground... and how would you ever know if you did change its color, since it's no longer visible?

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not seeing what this has to do with C++. Your code just looks like standard Processing code to me. Is there some connection there? 



If there's no link to C++ and it is really just Processing help you're after, I may be able to give you a hand if you are a bit clearer about exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and how your attempts have failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of integers to select the color (0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue).

```
int[] colSelect; // 0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue
```

Then, you can use this "selector" to choose the right fill color before drawing each circle.

```
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    if (colSelect[i] == 1) { 
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else if (colSelect[i] == 2) {
      fill(0, 0, 255);
    }
```

(There are multiple ways to do this - you can also use a switch statement.)

Now, you only have to make sure to increase the selector variable when a circle leaves the screen.

```
      colSelect[i]++;
      if (colSelect[i] > 2) {
        colSelect[i] = 0;
      }
```

I suggest you try to extend your code first without looking at the code below ;)

Here's your code with my suggestion inserted:

```
float[] circleX;
float[] circleY;
float[] circledia;
float[] speedY;
float[] speedX;
int[] colSelect; // 0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue
int asteroid = 10;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 700);
  background(188, 234, 255);

  circleX = new float[asteroid];
  circleY = new float[asteroid];
  circledia = new float[asteroid];
  speedX = new float[asteroid];
  speedY = new float[asteroid];
  colSelect = new int[asteroid];

  for (int i = 0; i < asteroid; i++)
  {
    circleX[i] = random(50, 500);
    circleY[i] = 0;
    circledia[i] = random(10, 50);
    speedX[i] = random(-2, 2);
    speedY[i] = random(2, 3);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(188, 234, 255);
  noStroke();
  fill(113, 69, 75);
  rect(0, 580, width, height);
  asteroidArr();
}

void asteroidArr()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < asteroid; i++)
  {
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    if (colSelect[i] == 1) { 
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else if (colSelect[i] == 2) {
      fill(0, 0, 255);
    }
    ellipse(circleX[i], circleY[i], circledia[i], circledia[i]);
    circleY[i] = circleY[i] + speedY[i];
    circleX[i] = circleX[i] + speedX[i];

    if (circleY[i] > 560 || circleX[i] < -10 || circleX[i] > 610)
    {
      circleY[i] = 0;
      circleX[i] = random(50, 500);
      circledia[i] = random(10, 50);
      speedY[i] = random(2, 2);
      speedX[i] = random(-2, 2);
      colSelect[i]++;
      if (colSelect[i] > 2) {
        colSelect[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helped.